# How can I alter the appearance of "Qt::IBeamCursor" in ReText?

Tags: theme, qt, gtk2

I'm running Lubuntu 12.10, fully updated. I used `apt-get` to install `ReText 3.1.4`, a **qt** app, and the various recommends.

I managed to get the page and font appearance to my liking by using Qt4 settings and CSS. But I cannot change the insertion bar's appearance from minimal width and black to something a little broader and red.

The image below shows the more visible cursor (insertion bar) I have in Leafpad text editor (gtk2) as well as the code I used. Can I get the equivalent effect in ReText?

[image: cursor]

I'm guessing what I want to change is described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#CursorShape-enum) as the `Qt::IBeamCursor`. So my question would specifically be: can `Qt::IBeamCursor` be modified by an end-user just by using CSS (and not something more technical)? In the context of `ReText`, I have a CSS file here: `~/.config/ReText project/ReText.css` which I've used to customize the color and size of text within `code` and `pre` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer of ReText, "Qt supports cursor customization (via QStyle::PM_TextCursorWidth), but unfortunately that's not exposed via QStyleSheetStyle". A bug has been filed for this feature: [Please allow customizing cursor width via CSS](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30326).